# NodeJS 'mongodb' client update function not working sometimes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

mongodb client version: 3.1.10

I am using hosted mongo db server on Mlab.com: Shared Production-Ready cluster.

```
var dbo = db.db(DB);
var collection = dbo.collection('schedule');

var query = {email:userEmail};

let availability = (availabilityArg==="offQ")?"no":"yes";
let note = (availabilityArg==="offQ")?"Off Queue":"";
var data = {available:availability,notes:note};

collection.update(query,{$set:data},function(err,data){
    if(err)
        console.log("DB find error.");
    else{
        console.log(userEmail+((availabilityArg==="offQ")?" off the queue":" back in queue"));
    }
});
```

The above works 95% of the time. 5% of the time, the DB does not get updated at all.

95%: The DB get's updated based on the `availabilityArg`. If it is `offQ`, the `available` attribute will be set to `no`. If it is `onQ`, the available attribute will be set to `yes`. The notes attribute also gets updated accordingly.

5%: The DB does not get updated at all. There's no change to the `available` attribute and the `notes` attribute. Though I see the console.log statement with the email ID and the `off the queue`/`back in queue` message.

It just doesn't make sense.

PS:
`function(db,userEmail, availabilityArg)`

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and re-imagined it as follows, I hope it helps.

```
/* 
    I am not sure what is going on behind here 
    so I'll just comment it out, and show you 
    an implementation that works, which you can
    repurpose.
*/

// var dbo = db.db(DB);
// var collection = dbo.collection('schedule');

/* 
    NOTE: Below is the an example model for handling data using mongoose,
    This should be in a separate file which you would import
*/

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    availability: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    notes: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
});

// If in the same file (not advisable)
const Schedule = mongoose.model('Schedule', schema, 'schedule_collection');

// Or export (advisable)
module.exports = mongoose.model('Schedule', schema, 'schedule_collection');


// NOTE: Below is a re-imagined version of your code

const findQuery = { email: userEmail };

const availability = availabilityArg === 'offQ' ? 'no' : 'yes';
const notes = availabilityArg === 'offQ' ? 'Off Queue' : '';

// NOTE: For updating the document 

const updateQuery = { 
    availability: availability, 
    notes: notes
};

// NOTE: Using findOneAndUpdate of the Model

Schedule.findOneAndUpdate(findQuery, updateQuery, (err, _) => {
    if (err)
        console.log("DB error.");
    else {
        console.log(userEmail + ((availabilityArg === "offQ") ? " off the queue" : " back in queue"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Kola, I really appreciate the code changes that you shared. This would definitely help us in the future. But currently, I am looking for a quick workaround. Changing the client package from `mongodb` to `mongoose` is going to be a task we would put off for a few months at this time.

Comment: You're welcome Tjs. Although with more information I could help. Cheers!

Comment: Grey, could you tell me what more info/data you need to help?

Comment: Tjs, kindly share what's going on here => var dbo = db.db(DB);